# Excel 2013 - Web Query connection string modification for multiple wksheets w/i workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I need to modify approximately 60 worksheets - connection string(s) to change 1 part of the criteria.  I found this code on stack overflow, however, I am getting an Run-time error 1004:  application defined or object defined error.  see (*)

```
    Sub ConnectionString_modify()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim modtext As String
    Dim modrange As String
    Dim conn
    'Grab nummber of workbook connections
    cnt = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count


    For i = cnt To 1 Step -1
    Set conn = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(i)
    modtext = conn.OLEDBConnection.Connection '**********
    modtext = VBA.Replace(modtext, "quickRange=NEXT_3_DAYS", "quickRange=PLUS_MINUS_3_DAYS")
    conn.OLEDBConnection.Connection = modtext
    conn.Name = VBA.Replace(conn.Name, "quickRange=NEXT_3_DAYS", "quickRange=PLUS_MINUS_3_DAYS")

    Next i

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Excel on my machine to check but I guess it's that you need to call the right method to get the string e.g.

```
modtext = OLEDBConnection.ConnectionString
```

rather than

```
modtext = OLEDBConnection.Connection
```